# How to generate PARTNER WSDL for previous version

Tags: partner-wsdl

My salesforce has a latest upgrade for API32.0.  So by default when i generate partner WSDL I get that in my WSDL.  How do I generate PARTNER WSDL for a older version say 30.0

Comment: why you need older WSDL?

Comment: I am using TIBCO API calls to Salesforce.  The maximum version that tibco allows is 30.0.  still i am also looking for the possibility that tibco can get the 32.0.  But in the mean time I wanted to check the other way round too

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is option in SFDC to get older version of WSDL.

One thing you can try is search for tools/ code library which used SOAP API and get WSDL from that.

One such example is PHP toolkit.

For your reference here is WSDL ver 27.

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/tree/master/soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/tree/master/soapclient

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get hold of old versions. We wanted to refer to old versions in our internal product so we end up creating this and adding various wsdls that we had.

If you have any wsdls which are not in the repo, please create a PR.

https://github.com/datasert/force-wsdls